# my website fits when my laptop's zoom is on 90% but on 100% overflows

Tags: css

I m building a website on my laptop by watching an instructor's video.I have to set the same pixels with him, to follow the design they gave me. BUT the design he follows,and i have to do so, fits only when my browser's zoom is 90%. When i zoom in 100% the content overflows.The items are shown as they should when my zoom is 90%. In other words the design i have to follow does not work on 100%, which is the default on my browser by the way.Any other website that i m just looking on internet works on 100% perfcetly.
i have set :
*
body margin 0
all sections background sizes cover or 100%

if i have to specify more details, please it would be helpful to let me know
Thank u in advance.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "SourceSansPro", serif;
}


@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    .container {
    width: 1360px;
   
}

header {
    height: 745px;
    padding-bottom: 90px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="app2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
    <body>
        <header>
            
            <div class="container">
```

Comment: Show us the relevant HTML + CSS please

Comment: Maybe also reduce the bodys padding to 0

Comment: You have set the width to 1360px even if a device has width less than that (down to 1200px). Is that where your overflow is coming from?

Comment: A Haworth , i had it 1240px.But  from the beggining, even without this @media..,just editing only for desktop does not work appropriately.According to the design it has to be 1360px. On 90% works perfect.

Comment: did you try setting your browser zoom in 100% and then refresh the page?

Comment: Psycho yes, it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a closing brackets error here:

```css
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    .container {
        width: 1360px; /* Why you set 1360px when min-width is 1280px? */
    } /* Need to close this */
}
```

To find out how to solve the problem, it would be advisable to publish the page's html and css. It would be the best if you also post a screenshot to make us understand better what happens.

Comment: i cannot upload my screenshots because i m new in this site.i ll try to specify better.thank u for your responses so far.